# Best Practise. How to store User Search preferences

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Example. I have a database for a dating website. User will want to search for other users and have this criteria saved in database.

Right now i have a table that stores this per user

```
Search Table
------------
ageLower = 21
ageUpper = 25
HairColorId = 44 (mapped to Blonde)
```

I then grab the each field from this table to perform a regular search.
E.g Where HairColorId = 44.
What is the most efficient way to search if a user wants to select more than 1 preference for example

```
Search Table
-----------
ageLower = 18
ageUpper = 25
```

HairColorId = 44,45 (Blonde or RedHead but not Brunette)

Does the Hair ColumnId become a text Field instead of int?
The Search will then be.. Where HairColourId in (44,45).

How do i handle input if the user decides hairColor isnt important?

Or Should i do away with this table Structure and construct search query from one large text field?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a SET type column. It allows you to specify a set of values for a single column, for example  hair colour, with a predefined set of values. You can do selects based on the values as you require. If you don't care about the value, you can just skip the column in your filter operation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set.html

Comment: Thanks, but i think this solution will require much maintenance